# Howto Replace TypeToken from Guava with Gson (Specificaly when using Generic Types)

Tags: java, generics, reflection, gson, guava

I am currently trying to refactor a project to avoid having to use guava as a dependency.
I was using it mainly for reflection related features, but in most case I could find an altenative.

However, there is one case left I cannot fix for now:
I try to retrieve the class of a generic parameter of the current class.

It works fine using `Guava` since the Type returned by `TokenType` can be casted to Class.

Guava:

`(Class<I>) new com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken<I>(getClass()) {}.getType();`

I attempted to substitute this call using the `TypeToken` from `Gson` instead, but apparently the information about I is lost and there result of this call is a `TypeVariable` than is kept as a Class after executing:

Gson:

`(Class<I>) new com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken<I>() {}.getType();`

As far as I can tell the getClass() parameter is a clue to why context is not kept.
When I use `Guava` with the same signature:

`(Class<I>) new com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken<I>() {}.getType();`

I get this error message:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot construct a TypeToken for a type variable.
>   You probably meant to call new TypeToken(getClass()) that can resolve the type variable for you.
>   If you do need to create a TypeToken of a type variable, please use TypeToken.of() instead.

I see `Gson` also as a (package protected) constructor using a `Type` as argument.

Is there a way to obtain the class of a Generic Parameter using `Gson` only ?

### Edit #1:

Understanding the issue a bit better I can say that the difference seems to be located in the underlying Type implementation returned by the two methods.

The Guava one can be casted to `Class<I>` whereas the Gson one cannot. I am not sure what the underlying implementation for Guava is yet, but the Gson one uses a `TypeVariable`.

At the moment the workaround I found was to exploit the two information Guava uses (Type + current class) by merging the result of the Gson TypeToken (Type) with this method that uses the current class as context:

```
public static Type getActualType(Class context, Type parameterizedType) {
    if (parameterizedType instanceof TypeVariableImpl) {
        TypeVariable[] genericParameters = context.getSuperclass().getTypeParameters();
        Type[] implementations = ((ParameterizedTypeImpl) context.getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments();
        for (int i = 0; i < genericParameters.length; i++) {
            if (genericParameters[i].getName().equals(((TypeVariableImpl) parameterizedType).getName())) {
                return implementations[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return parameterizedType;
}
```

(this implementation comes from the [buremba/netty-rest project](https://github.com/buremba/netty-rest/blob/master/src/main/java/org/rakam/server/http/SwaggerReader.java#L806))

This allows me to retrieve the expected class by calling:

`(Class<I>) getActualType(getClass(), new com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken<I>() {}.getType());`

This seems a bit laborious, I am not sure this is the best way to do it.

Note: The question was also raised as [a Github issue on the Gson Project](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1414)

Comment: What forbids you to copy Guava's `TypeToken` in your codebase? That code is under Apache Licence and you can reuse it.

Comment: Sure.. I looked into it but the TypeToken class from Guava dependends on lot of classes from guava (packages reflect, io, collection, ...). In that case it would be easier to keep guava as dependency (makes it easy to update and manage).

Comment: Oh, ok, I didn't know: I haven't checked that class' source code yet.

Comment: but you know that creating type like `(Class<I>)` is basically just using raw types in terms of reflections? If you want to warp class into token use `TypeToken.of(class)`